# PHP writes file to localhost but not on IIS 8

Tags: php, iis, iis-8, file-put-contents

Please assist, I am writing a file to my `applicationdir/uploads/` folder.
When writing the file out on my localhost via `wamp64 host`, the file generates perfectly.

However, when I attempt this on my `IIS 8.0 server`, The form submits, no errors are thrown, but the file is not created...

I am using the `File_Put_Contents` command to create the file.

I have read through other posts and as indicated by others, I have changed my `applicationpool\MYAppPool` name to resemble the application name(to no avail). I have also allowed the `iis_iusrs` permissions to write to the directory.

Any thoughts?
PHP BELOW:

```
<?php
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && !empty( $_POST['xml'] ) ){
        $Counter = date("Y-m-d") . ' ' . Time();
        $file  = 'uploads/' . $Counter . ' - Export.xml';
        $bytes = file_put_contents( $file, $_POST['xml'] );
        exit( sprintf('%d bytes written to %s',$bytes,realpath($file) ) );
    }
?>
```

Screenshot:

[On Submit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hAzOD.png)

I don't see how this will make a difference but here is the javascript code passing the xml data to the server.
Javascript:

```
<script>
   var template = [
              '<?xml version="1.0"?>',
              '<unattend xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:unattend">',
              '<Data>',
              ' <SubmitBy><?SubmitBy?></SubmitBy>',
              ' <Level10><?Level10?></Level10>',
              ' <Level1><?Level1?></Level1>',
              ' <Level2><?Level2?></Level2>',
              ' <Level3><?Level3?></Level3>',
              ' <Level4><?Level4?></Level4>',
              ' <Title><?Title?></Title>',
              ' <Subject><?Subject?></Subject>',
              ' <Author><?Author?></Author>',
              ' <Keywords1><?Keywords1?></Keywords1>',
              ' <Keywords2><?Keywords2?></Keywords2>',
              ' <Destroy_Date><?Destroy_Date?></Destroy_Date>',
              '</Data>',
              '</unattend>'
            ].join('\r\n');


            const ajax=function( params ){
                with( new XMLHttpRequest() ){
                    onreadystatechange=function(e){
                        if( this.status==200 && this.readyState==4 ){
                            alert( this.response )
                        }
                    }
                    open( 'POST', location.href, true );
                    setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
                    send( params );
                }
            }

            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ()=>{
                document.querySelector('input[ type="button" ]').addEventListener('click', e=>{
                    let vars={};                    
                    Array.prototype.slice.call( document.querySelectorAll('form > input[ type="text" ]') ).forEach( field =>{
                     vars[ field.name ]=field.value
                      });
                       Array.prototype.slice.call( document.querySelectorAll('select') ).forEach( field =>{
                     vars[ field.name ]=field.value
                      });
                         Array.prototype.slice.call( document.querySelectorAll('form > input[ type="date" ]') ).forEach( field =>{
                     vars[ field.name ]=field.value
                      });
                    let xml=template.replace(/<\?(\w+)\?>/ig, (match,name)=>{
                        return vars[name];
                    });
                    ajax.call( this, 'xml='+xml);
                })
            });
        </script>
```

Comment: What is the error message exactly ?

Comment: This seems to be my issue... There is no error message... The form submits and displays my POST correctly when submitting, it just doesn't seem to create the file though.

Comment: try to test like `if(file_put_contents($file, $content) === false) {echo 'something wrong happens'; }` just to double check that nothing happens

Comment: Added the code, message did not display, just submitted as usual...

Comment: then i don't know where you are writting, but it looks like you are creating the file somewhere

Comment: Where's your code? I see none in your post. Additionally, which error level have you configured?

Comment: is `sprintf('%d bytes written to %s',$bytes,realpath($file)` display anything ?

Comment: `file_put_contents()` will return `false` on failure. You're not checking for this, so it may fail but appear to work.

Comment: @MacBooc all that displays is a dialog with all my code and a "ok" button.

Comment: @Spudley what could I add here to display the exact error message if false?

Comment: Note: What is weird is that all of this works perfectly on my local apache server, this issue is specific to iis.

Comment: i don't think so, i work on both with the exact same code, i never had this kind of problem

Comment: "*all that displays is a dialog with all my code*" ... so that means the code isn't being run at all, and IIS is simply sending you the code file as if it was a text file. This implies that your IIS is not configured to run PHP. Check your IIS config.

Comment: @Spudley When running the site on WAMP, I have no issues creating the file, it still prompts with all my html and the "OK" button but seems to work fine.
IIS: I have php manager installed along with php 5.5. Any ideas of what specifically I can check to resolve this? or perhaps any php/JS code that would write out the error to my site?

Comment: I Managed to resolve this issue.
The issue was that the IIS configuration - Default Document was not set correctly.
It was looking for the "default.htm" file instead of the "Index.php" file.